# No matching function for call to copy constructor

Tags: c++, no-match

I have a class Graph whose copy constructor is declared in Graph.h like this:

```
template<typename Object,typename Weight>              
Graph<Object,Weight>::Graph(Graph<Object,Weight>& G)
```

Elsewhere, I try to use it:

```
Graph<double,double> G = make_graph("dense.g");
```

...but it gives me the following error:

```
time_trialsALIST.cpp:37: error: no matching function for call to `Graph::Graph(Graph)'
Graph.h:142: note: candidates are: Graph::Graph(Graph&) [with Object = double, Weight = double]
```

I don't understand why this would happen; the make_graph function just returns a Graph:

```
Graph<double,double>  make_graph(string filename){...}
```

Do I need an '&' somewhere?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ Templates: implicit conversion, no matching function for call to ctor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628646/c-templates-implicit-conversion-no-matching-function-for-call-to-ctor)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Read the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602058/why-is-the-copy-constructor-argument-const). In other words, you're missing a `const`, not an `&`. Make it:

```
template<typename Object,typename Weight>              
Graph<Object,Weight>::Graph(const Graph<Object,Weight>& G)
```

You can't bind a temporary to a non-const reference.